# How to return the minimum distance between matching numbers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find the minimum distance between two matching numbers in an unsorted array. If it is impossible to find a match return -1.
The array I am using int[] array = {5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7};

I have tried two for loops and two helper methods comparing the first element to the other elements in the array and increasing the counter variable by one until I reach the match. Then I compare the counter to the min, which I set as the highest maximum Integer possible. I'm not sure why it's not working. For this example it is supposed to return 4.

```java
int[] array = {5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7};

         int counter = 0;
         int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
         if(hasDuplicates(array)) {
             for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                 for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                    if(array[i] != array[j]){
                     counter++;
                    }
                 }
                 min = min(counter, min);
                 counter = 0;
             }

             System.out.println(min);
         } else {
             System.out.println("-1");
         }
    }

    public static boolean hasDuplicates(int[] array) {
        boolean isDuplicates = false;
        Set<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int element : array){
            if(duplicates.contains(element)) {
                isDuplicates = true;
            }
            duplicates.add(element);
        }
        return isDuplicates;
    }

    public static int min(int a, int b){
        if (a >b){
            return a;
        } else {
            return b;
        }
    }
```

I expect the output of this method to be 4, but the actual output of this code is 2147483647.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've just figured where the problem is.

In the original codes, you should not try to use a counter for helping to find out the distance if both numbers not match. Instead, you can try to calculate the distance directly if both match each other.

The code would be like this:

```
public void find() {

    int[] array = {5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7};

    //int counter = 0;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if(hasDuplicates(array)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                /*if(array[i] != array[j]){
                    counter++;
                }*/
                if(array[i] == array[j]){
                    min = Math.min(min, j - i);
                }
            }
            //min = min(counter, min);
            /*if (counter > 0)
                min = Math.min(counter, min);
            counter = 0;*/
        }

        System.out.println(min);
    } else {
        System.out.println("-1");
    }
}
```

Then you would get **3**.

Answer (score 1):

2147483647 is integer Max value. Your min function is actually returning max of the two parameters. Change the comparison to less than.

```
public static int min(int a, int b){ if (a <b){ return a; } else { return b; }
```

Or use Math.min.